# Qual a diferença de desempenho entre BIGINT e o INT no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho

Há algum impacto negativo na performance do MySQL, onde a *Primary Key* é do tipo `BIGINT(20)`, ao invés de `INT(11)`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Qual a diferença entre `INT` e `BIGINT`?**

Vamos retornar ao manual primeiro, em [`10.2.1 Tipos Inteiros`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html), temos o seguinte:

```
INT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
```

> Um número inteiro de tamanho normal. O intervalo assinado está entre -2147483648 a 2147483647.
>   O intervalo não assinado vai de 0 a 4294967295.

```
BIGINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
```

> Um número inteiro grande. O intervalo assinado está entre -9223372036854775808 e 9223372036854775807.
>   O intervalo não assinado vai de 0 a 18446744073709551615.

Ok, então, um `INT` pode alocar valores até 2.1 bilhões e um BIGINT pode alocar um valor qualquer de até `20 dígitos`.

**Então, o que importa?**

Muita coisa, na verdade. Utilizar `INT` ao invés de `BIGINT` pode reduzir significamente o uso em disco. Se somente esta opção de `INT` ao invés de `BIGINT` pode fazê-lo economizar de 10% a 20% de espaço em disco (dependendo da situação). Melhor ainda, se utilizado como `chave primária` e como `chaves estrangeiras` e `indexes`, a redução do seu `index` pode chegar a **50%** e com isto, promover a performance quando estas indexes forem utilizadas.

Answer (score 11):

Essencialmente não há. Pode até ter alguma diferença marginal mas nada que seja importante e até mesmo será difícil medir, quanto mais atrapalhar alguma coisa. E se houver, será mais por consequências do tamanho do que pelo tipo em si.

Dito isto, dificilmente você precisará de um `BIGINT` para uma chave primária. Se não precisa, não use. E se precisar, então deveria usar ele, mesmo que a performance fosse pior.

Obviamente você não deve usar nada com tamanho maior do que necessita, economizar espaço sempre é uma coisa boa se não for a custo de outra coisa importante.

Portanto use o que precisa e não se preocupe com a performance em casos assim.

Em banco de dados, pequenos ganhos de performance são completamente irrelevantes. É a pior forma de micro otimização.

A resposta aceita fala em ganhos significativos, mas na verdade eles são irrisórios na maioria das vezes ou bem pouco significativos nas outras. Não há por exemplo um ganho de 50% em índices porque o índice não é composto só pela chave, é bem mais complexo que isso, e esse ganho deve ser em 1 ou outro índice, a maioria deles não terá esse ganho.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

A diferença está em relação a alocação de espaço na base de dados, consequentemente no uso de disco, memória RAM, memória cache, transferências de dados, rede etc.

Enquanto INT aloca 4 bytes, o BIGINT aloca o dobro, 8 bytes.

Use BIGINT somente se houver necessidade de armazenar valores superiores a 4294967295 (unsigned) ou 2147483647 (signed).